# SharePoint Online, Ribbon Custom Action - pass multiple id's instead of standard 'SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}'

Tags: url, custom-actions, parameter

How do You pass custom values from Custom Actions? I can create custom Custom Action and it works well with one listitem, but how to include my custom parameter in Custom Action?

[image]

As I understand, there is only limited set of tokens, like {ItemUrl}, {ListId}, etc.

[image]

The only way I see now - is to use cookies to store selected values and read them on target page; but imho it is ugly solution, maybe I can include my params in Custom Action url string?..